# How does SocialMediaData determine vertex size

Tags: graphs-and-networks, social-media

How does SocialMediaData determine the size of graph vertices, e.g. on what does the vertex size depend in, say, a Facebook friend network graph?

Answer (score 1):

It's scaled by vertex degree, i.e., the number of mutual friends.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a reference to the source of this assertion?

Comment: It's confirmed by Wolfram research.

Comment: Where? Personal communication or documentation center or...?

Comment: Personal communication (tech support) .. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that...